# Why do scientists perform most of biological experiments done on rats prior to humans?

Tags: human-biology

Why do scientists perform most of biological experiments done on rats prior to humans?

> Scientist gave a third ear to this rat
>
> [image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacanti_mouse)

Here is the another [source](https://www.brusselstimes.com/all-news/94548/researchers-in-london-test-coronavirus-vaccine-on-rats/) claiming Researchers wants to COVID - 19 vaccine on rats.

Comment: [World's scientists admit they just don't like mice](https://www.theonion.com/worlds-scientists-admit-they-just-dont-like-mice-1819567643)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Also that is a mouse not a rat! ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: @tyresome I added second sources, still how many sources are needed for my question? Any specific number?

Comment: Some sign of researching the answer to question on your own first, please read the homework policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally for practical reasons.  Rats and mice breed prolifically and are easy to keep in captivity.  (Imagine trying to perform lab experiments on say hippotami, or tigers :-))  I would also imagine, given the large number of rat & mouse traps & poisons sold, that the fact that few people would care what was done to rats might have factored into it.

As time went on, those particular animals became the entrenched experimental animals, as techniques and equipment for maintaining them became readily available.  Indeed, you can readily buy commercial rat & mouse food: https://multipurina.ca/en/rodents/products/  Various lab strains were developed having consistent characteristics such as genetics or susceptibility to cancer.  (Not my field, so someone more knowledgeable could perhaps expand on this.)

Answer (score -4):

You can do a google search. However,
The rodent lineage, which gave rise to the rat and mouse, and the primate lineage, which gave rise to humans, diverged about 80 million years ago. Humans have 23 pairs of chromosomes, while rats have 21 and mice have 20. However, the new analysis found chromosomes from all three organisms to be **related to each other by about 280 large regions of genomic sequence similarity - called "syntenic blocks"** - distributed in varying patterns across the organisms' chromosomes. (More at [genome.gov](https://www.genome.gov/11511308/2004-release-scientists-compare-rat-genome))

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It isn't clear why you think this answers the question, which probably isn't a good fit for this site anyway. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome well, this is what he needed